# Setting up PHPMyAdmin on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I've installed PHPMyAdmin on my Amazon EC2 instance using the following:

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install phpmyadmin
```

Then symlinked it to /var/www/html with

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html
```

When I navigate to /phpmyadmin in my browser, it gives me a 403 Forbidden saying I can't access /phpmyadmin/ on the server.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

from [here](http://sanketdangi.com/post/56623052533/phpmyadmin-on-amazon-ec2-manage-amazon-rds) you should edit phpMyAdmin.conf to allow the access